# Where can I change the DSpace's Searche Box style?

Tags: dspace

I can't find the DSpace's .css style sheet to change the style of the Search Box. This is the code of the button:

```
<form method="get" action="/simple-search" class="form-horizontal col-md-12 form-group form-group-lg" scope="search" role="form">
                            
        <br><br>
    <div class="col-md-12 searchbox">
        <div class="col-md-11">
            <input type="text" class="form-control " placeholder="Buscar na Biblioteca" name="query" id="tequery-main-page" size="25">
        </div>              
        <div class="col-md-1">
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right search-button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    
    </form>
```

Comment: I would be interested too. Could an expert or in better case a dspace developer answer this? Thx.

Comment: I created chat room for dspace. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227459/dspace-repository-guide-help-room